# The right event to apply "scrollTo" to show a dynamically added nested panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1, extjs6-modern

I have a panel in ExtJS6 modern (mobile) application that can scroll vertically only. Sub panels are added dynamically to it. I need to scroll the panel to its end after adding a new sub-panel in order to make it visible. This is done using this line:

```
Ext.getCmp('tabmainMessagesPanel').getScrollable().scrollTo(Infinity, Infinity, true);
```

I execute this line in a button click, and it works (but need to click the button manually). I tried to find the right event where I can add this line to do the scroll automatically, without success. I nearly tried all the possible relevant events of the sub-panel: show, add, added, activate, ... I also tried the events of the parent panel without success.

Apparently, these events happen before the scroller of the parent panel takes into account the added sub-panel, so it scrolls to the before-last one. I smell asynchronous behavior here. The proof is that I call the `scrollTo` method in a delayed task of 0.5 second and it works. But this solution is not reliable.

The question is: where (in which event of which component) this line of code should go in order to scroll the parent to its end correctly?

[EDIT]

Here is the part of the code concerning the question. First, the `Message` class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.message.Message', {
    extend : 'Ext.Panel', 
    xtype : 'message',

    layout : 'hbox',
    config : {
        mBody : ''
    },

    listeners: {
        added: function (element) {
            MyApp.view.main.Global.scroller.delay(500); //start a delayed task to scroll parent panel
        }
    }, 

    items: [
                {
                    flex : 1
                },
                {
                    maxWidth: '80%',
                    width: 'auto',
                    html : '<div class="myClass">' + this.getMBody() + '</div>'
                }
    ]
});
```

Here is the delayed task that scrolls the parent panel `tabmainMessagesPanel` to its end in order to show the newly-added message:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Global', {
    statics: {
        scroller: Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
         Ext.getCmp('tabmainMessagesPanel').getScrollable().scrollTo(Infinity, Infinity, true);  
        })
    }
}
```

Now, the tab panel that contains the panel `tabmainMessagesPanel` that will contain the messages:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.TabMain', {
extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
mixins : [ 'Ext.mixin.Responsive' ],
xtype : 'tabmain',

responsiveConfig : {
    portrait : {
        items : 
        [ 
        {
            title : 'Messages',
            layout : 'vbox',

            items : [ {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout : 'vbox',
                height: '100%',
                id: 'tabmainMessagesPanel',
                scrollable : 'vertical',
                style : 'background-color:#F0F0F0'
            },
            {
                xtype : 'inputfield',
                docked : 'bottom'
            }]
        }, 
        {
            title : 'Connect',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items : [
                  //some UI elements
            ]
        }
        ]
    },

    //--------------------------------------------------

    landscape : {
        // same as portrait
    }
},

//--------------------------------------------------

controller : 'tabmain',
viewModel : 'tabmain',

defaults : {
    tab : {
        iconAlign : 'top'
    },
    styleHtmlContent : true
}

});
```

Finally, this is an event in a controller that creates and adds a message to `tabmainMessagesPanel` whenever a new message arrives:

```
handle_message: function (mess) {
     var p = Ext.create('MyApp.view.message.Message', {
          mBody : mess.body
        });
    Ext.getCmp('tabmainMessagesPanel').add(p);
}
```

Comment: @Brett I added code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for this. I found it 6 months later. I post it here for the benefit of those who may have the same issue.

The solution is to define the event `refresh` of the scroller of the panel `tabmainMessagesPanel`, and scroll to the end in it. So, the definition of the panel `tabmainMessagesPanel` becomes:

```
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout : 'vbox',
            height: '100%',
            id: 'tabmainMessagesPanel',
            scrollable : 'vertical',
            listeners: {
                initialize: function (me) {
                    me.getScrollable().on('refresh', function () {
                        me.getScrollable().scrollTo(Infinity, Infinity, true);
                    }); 
                }
            },
            style : 'background-color:#F0F0F0'
        }
```